# OpenGL: How do I add a Shadow Map to my scene?

Tags: opengl, shadow

So I have a scene in OpenGL, I'm using the tutorial from this site:
http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/
(NO, I can't use a different base)

And I need to add a shadow map. I was told to use this site:
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial23/tutorial23.html
(NO, I ...... probably can't use a different site, although I'm desperate)

Here's the code I used:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <glutil/glutil.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "../framework/framework.h"
#include "../framework/Mesh.h"
#include "../framework/MousePole.h"
#include "../framework/Timer.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glimg/glimg.h>

#define ARRAY_COUNT( array ) (sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * (sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))))

struct ProgramData
{
    GLuint theProgram;

    GLuint modelToCameraMatrixUnif;

    GLuint objectColorUnif;
    GLuint cameraToClipMatrixUnif;

    GLuint lightIntensityUnif;
    GLuint ambientIntensityUnif;

    GLuint normalModelToCameraMatrixUnif;
    GLuint cameraSpaceLightPosUnif;
    GLuint windowSizeUnif;
    GLuint lightAttenuationUnif;
    GLuint bUseRSquareUnif;
    GLuint shininessFactorUnif;
    GLuint numberTextureUnif;
};


float g_fzNear = 1.0f;
float g_fzFar = 1000.0f;

ProgramData g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor;
ProgramData g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex;

ProgramData LoadLitProgram(const std::string &strVertexShader, const std::string &strFragmentShader)
{
    std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;

    shaderList.push_back(Framework::LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, strVertexShader));
    shaderList.push_back(Framework::LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, strFragmentShader));

    ProgramData data;
    data.theProgram = Framework::CreateProgram(shaderList);
    data.modelToCameraMatrixUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "modelToCameraMatrix");

    data.cameraToClipMatrixUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "cameraToClipMatrix");

    data.lightIntensityUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "lightIntensity");
    data.ambientIntensityUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "ambientIntensity");
    data.shininessFactorUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "shininessFactor");

    data.normalModelToCameraMatrixUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "normalModelToCameraMatrix");
    data.cameraSpaceLightPosUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "cameraSpaceLightPos");
    data.windowSizeUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "windowSize");
    data.lightAttenuationUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "lightAttenuation");
    data.bUseRSquareUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "bUseRSquare");
    data.objectColorUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "objectColor");

    data.numberTextureUnif = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "numberTexture");

    return data;
}

void InitializePrograms()
{
    g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor = LoadLitProgram("FragLightAtten_PCN.vert", "FragLightAtten.frag");
    g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex = LoadLitProgram("FragLightAtten_PCN.vert", "FragLightAttentex.frag");
}


GLuint g_samplers[1];
GLuint g_textures[5];


Framework::Mesh *g_pCylinderMesh = NULL;
Framework::Mesh *g_pPlaneMesh = NULL; 

void LoadTexture()
{

    glGenSamplers(1, &g_samplers[0]);

    glSamplerParameteri(g_samplers[0], GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glSamplerParameteri(g_samplers[0], GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glSamplerParameteri(g_samplers[0], GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glSamplerParameteri(g_samplers[0], GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);


    glGenTextures(5, &g_textures[0]);

    //cylinder
    std::string filename(Framework::FindFileOrThrow("13_grass.jpg"));
    std::auto_ptr<glimg::ImageSet> pImageSet(glimg::loaders::stb::LoadFromFile(filename.c_str()));
    glimg::SingleImage image = pImageSet->GetImage(0, 0, 0);
    glimg::Dimensions dims = image.GetDimensions();
    glimg::OpenGLPixelTransferParams pxTrans = glimg::GetUploadFormatType(pImageSet->GetFormat(), 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textures[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, dims.width, dims.height, 0,
    pxTrans.format, pxTrans.type, image.GetImageData());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);


}



//Called after the window and OpenGL are initialized. Called exactly once, before the main loop.
void init()
{
    InitializePrograms();

    try
    {
        g_pCylinderMesh = new Framework::Mesh("UnitCylinder.xml");
        g_pPlaneMesh = new Framework::Mesh("LargePlane.xml");
    }
    catch(std::exception &except)
    {
        printf("%s\n", except.what());
        throw;
    }

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    const float depthZNear = 0.0f;
    const float depthZFar = 1.0f;

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthRange(depthZNear, depthZFar);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);


    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

    LoadTexture();
}







static float g_fLightHeight = 1.5f;
static float g_fLightRadius = 1.0f;
static bool g_bUseRSquare = true;

static float g_fLightAttenuation = 1.0f;

float zl=0.0f,xl=4.0f,yl=2.0f;

//calculating the light
 using Framework::Timer;
Timer g_LightTimer(Timer::TT_LOOP, 5.0f);
void CalcLightPosition()
{
    float fCurrTimeThroughLoop = g_LightTimer.GetAlpha();

    glm::vec4 ret(0.0f, g_fLightHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    xl = cosf(fCurrTimeThroughLoop * (3.14159f * 2.0f)) * g_fLightRadius;
    zl = sinf(fCurrTimeThroughLoop * (3.14159f * 2.0f)) * g_fLightRadius;


}

void display()
{
    g_LightTimer.Update();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutil::MatrixStack persMatrix;
    persMatrix.Perspective(45.0f, (500 / (float)500), g_fzNear, g_fzFar);

    glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.theProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.cameraToClipMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(persMatrix.Top()));
    glUniform2i(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.windowSizeUnif, 500, 500);

    glUseProgram(0);



    glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.theProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.cameraToClipMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(persMatrix.Top()));
    glUniform2i(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.windowSizeUnif, 500, 500);

    glUseProgram(0);





    if(g_pPlaneMesh && g_pCylinderMesh)
    {
        glutil::MatrixStack modelMatrix;
        modelMatrix.SetMatrix(g_viewPole.CalcMatrix());



        const glm::vec4 &worldLightPos = glm::vec4(xl, yl, zl, 1.0f);

        const glm::vec4 &lightPosCameraSpace = modelMatrix.Top() * worldLightPos;


        glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.theProgram);
        glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.lightIntensityUnif, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.ambientIntensityUnif, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        glUniform3fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.cameraSpaceLightPosUnif,1, glm::value_ptr(lightPosCameraSpace));
        glUniform1f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.lightAttenuationUnif, g_fLightAttenuation);
        glUniform1i(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.bUseRSquareUnif, g_bUseRSquare ? 1 : 0);
        glUniform1f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.shininessFactorUnif, 0.2f);
        glUseProgram(0);



        glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.theProgram);
        glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.lightIntensityUnif, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.ambientIntensityUnif, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        glUniform3fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.cameraSpaceLightPosUnif,1, glm::value_ptr(lightPosCameraSpace));
        glUniform1f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.lightAttenuationUnif, g_fLightAttenuation);
        glUniform1i(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.bUseRSquareUnif, g_bUseRSquare ? 1 : 0);
        glUseProgram(0);




        {
            glutil::PushStack push(modelMatrix);

            //Render the ground plane.

            {
                glutil::PushStack push(modelMatrix);

                glm::mat3 normMatrix(modelMatrix.Top());
                normMatrix = glm::transpose(glm::inverse(normMatrix));

                glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.theProgram);
                glUniformMatrix4fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
                    glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix.Top()));

                glUniformMatrix3fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.normalModelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
                    glm::value_ptr(normMatrix));
                glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.objectColorUnif, 0.2f, 0.84f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
                g_pPlaneMesh->Render();
                glUseProgram(0);
            }

            //light
            if(g_bDrawLight)
            {
                glutil::PushStack push(modelMatrix);

                //light time
                CalcLightPosition();

                modelMatrix.Translate(xl, yl, zl);
                modelMatrix.Scale(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

                glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.theProgram);
                glUniformMatrix4fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
                    glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix.Top()));
                glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.objectColorUnif, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                g_pCubeMesh->Render("flat");
            }

            //cylinder
            {
                glutil::PushStack push(modelMatrix);

                modelMatrix.ApplyMatrix(g_objtPole.CalcMatrix());

                glm::mat3 normMatrix(modelMatrix.Top());
                normMatrix = glm::transpose(glm::inverse(normMatrix));
                modelMatrix.Translate(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                    glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.theProgram);

                    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 5);
                    glBindSampler(1, g_samplers[0]);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textures[0]);
                    glUniform1i(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.numberTextureUnif, 5);

                    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
                        glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix.Top()));

                    glUniformMatrix3fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.normalModelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
                        glm::value_ptr(normMatrix));
                    glUniform4f(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColortex.objectColorUnif, 0.452f, 0.623f, 0.592f, 1.0f);
                    g_pCylinderMesh->Render();

                glUseProgram(0);
            }


        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//Called whenever the window is resized. The new window size is given, in pixels.
//This is an opportunity to call glViewport or glScissor to keep up with the change in size.
void reshape (int w, int h)
{
    glutil::MatrixStack persMatrix;
    persMatrix.Perspective(45.0f, (w / (float)h), g_fzNear, g_fzFar);

    glUseProgram(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.theProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.cameraToClipMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(persMatrix.Top()));
    glUniform2i(g_FragWhiteDiffuseColor.windowSizeUnif, w, h);

    glUseProgram(0);

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glutPostRedisplay();

}
```

Comment: And your question is? Just pasting a dump of code, while helpful for analysis tells us not what your problem is specifically. Also the arcsynthesis tutorial is a very good, recommended one; *great choice!* (really).

Comment: Even if it is great, it's confusing and now I'm to use a code from a different website to create a shadow map and no matter how hard I think about it, I cannot get this to work.

Comment: Ok, let's approach this from a different angle: You said yourself you just used some code you found somewhere on the Internet. When you did so, did you do this in the knowledge of how shadow maps actually work? Or was your approach simple "copy'n'paste" without actually knowing how shadow mapping actually works on a fundamental level. **This is important for us to know, so that we can write an answer that's useful for you.**

Comment: I admit, I did explain this poorly, I'm very sorry. Saddest thing is, I figured out the solution myself...... my XML files didn't have the texcord information included. I'm so sorry!